# File /var/log/messages Doesn't Exist - openSUSE

Tags: opensuse

I use openSUSE Leap 42.3 and there is no file `/var/log/messages`. How is that possible? I have seen that in this file are logs regarding my system.

**Edit**

Trying to install rsyslog I get

```
sudo zypper install rsyslog

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: systemd-logger-228-38.1.x86_64 conflicts with namespace:otherproviders(syslog) provided by rsyslog-8.24.0-1.3.x86_64
 Solution 1: deinstallation of systemd-logger-228-38.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install rsyslog-8.24.0-1.3.x86_64
```

Also the files in the `/var/log` are:

1. alternatives.log
2. boot.log
3. pbl.log
4. snapper.log
5. zypper.log

Comment: I assume you don't have a syslog daemon installed.  Check to see if `rsyslog` or something similar is present.  edit: in fact it looks like openSUSE no longer installs a syslog daemon by default, using `systemd` for logging instead (since it appears `systemd` always logs).

Comment: @EightBitTony Trying to install it, it says that it is present.

Comment: Update your question with the command you're using and the output?  It may be installed but not actually running as well.

Comment: @EightBitTony You mean the command for the installation?

Comment: Yup.  Also, what other files are in `/var/log/`?  Is it just `messages` that's missing?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSUSE appears to no longer install a syslog daemon by default, instead relying on the `systemd` logging and `journalctl`.

Your two options are,

1. use `journalctl` or
2. install a syslog daemon and ensure it's running

`systemd-logger-228-38.1.x86_64` is a dummy package, just remove it and let it install `rsyslog`.